# want to display sub menus using the show_menus array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

- want to display sub menus using the show_menus array .
- I am working javascript object array.
- show_menus array is dynamic .

> ```
> <script>
>      var show_menus = ['sub_menu_2', 'sub_menu_3'];
>             var items = [{
>                 label: 'menu1',
>                 items: [
>                     { label: 'sub_menu_1', icon: 'fa-plus' },
>                     { label: 'sub_menu_2', icon: 'fa-download' }
>                 ]
>             },
>             {
>                 label: 'menu2',
>                 items: [
>                     { label: 'sub_menu_3', icon: 'fa-refresh' },
>                     { label: 'sub_menu_4', icon: 'fa-repeat' }
>                 ]
>             }];
>
>             var my_menus = items.map(el => {
>                 return el.items;
>             });
>
>            var menues_two = my_menus.filter(word =>{
>
>            });
>
> </script>
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want. But If it's not then probably I misunderstood your problem.

```js
var show_menus = ['sub_menu_2', 'sub_menu_3'];
var items = [{
    label: 'menu1',
    items: [{
        label: 'sub_menu_1',
        icon: 'fa-plus'
      },
      {
        label: 'sub_menu_2',
        icon: 'fa-download'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    label: 'menu2',
    items: [{
        label: 'sub_menu_3',
        icon: 'fa-refresh'
      },
      {
        label: 'sub_menu_4',
        icon: 'fa-repeat'
      }
    ]
  }
];

var my_menus = items.map(el => {
  return el.items;
});
//console.log(my_menus);


var menues_two = [];

my_menus.forEach(word => {
  var men = word.filter(elm => {
    return show_menus.includes(elm['label']);
  });
  menues_two.push(men);
});

console.log(menues_two);
```